# Eloqua BulkAPI 2.0 returns 404: There was a validation error

Tags: data-integration, eloqua

I am trying to create a contacts export in Eloqua following [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAB/index.html#Developers/BulkAPI/Endpoints/Contacts/Exports/post-contacts-exports.htm).

The outcome I experience is:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 There was a validation error.
{
    "failures": [{
        "field": "name",
        "constraint": "Must be a string value, at least 1 character and at most 100 characters long."
    },
    {
        "field": "fields",
        "constraint": "Is required."
    }]
}
```

and makes no sense.

My requests are as follows:

`POST https://<HOST>.eloqua.com/API/Bulk/2.0/contacts/exports`

**Request Body**:

```
{
    "name": "Sample Contacts Export",
    "fields": {
        "UniqueId": "{{Contact.Id}}",
        "Subject": "{{Contact.Id}}",
        "FirstName": "{{Contact.Field(C_FirstName)}}",
        "LastName": "{{Contact.Field(C_LastName)}}",
        "Email": "{{Contact.Field(C_EmailAddress)}}",
        "Company": "{{Contact.Field(C_Company)}}",
        "JobTitle": "{{Contact.Field(C_Title)}}",
        "Address": "{{Contact.Field(C_Address1)}}",
        "City": "{{Contact.Field(C_City)}}",
        "Country": "{{Contact.Field(C_Country)}}",
        "Province": "{{Contact.Field(C_State_Prov)}}",
        "PostalCode": "{{Contact.Field(C_Zip_Postal)}}",
        "Phone": "{{Contact.Field(C_BusPhone)}}",
        "MobilePhone": "{{Contact.Field(C_MobilePhone)}}"
    }
}
```

and

`POST https://<HOST>.eloqua.com/API/Bulk/2.0/contacts/exports`

**Request Body**:

```
{
    "name":"Contact email export",
    "fields":{
        "EmailAddress":"{{Contact.Field(C_EmailAddress)}}"
    }
}
```

The latter is actually the example from the tutorial.

Do you have any idea what's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please, make sure you are adding the following header to the post request:

```
Content-Type application/json
```

*I can reproduce your error if the header is omitted.*

**Request WITHOUT content-type**

```
POST /API/Bulk/2.0/contacts/exports HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic *****

Body:
{
    "name":"Contact email export",
    "fields":{
        "EmailAddress":"{{Contact.Field(C_EmailAddress)}}"
    }
}
```

**Response WITHOUT content-type**

```
{
  "failures": [
    {
      "field": "name",
      "constraint": "Must be a string value, at least 1 character and at most 100 characters long."
    },
    {
      "field": "fields",
      "constraint": "Is required."
    }
  ],...
}
```

**Request with content-type**

```
POST /API/Bulk/2.0/contacts/exports HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic *****
Content-Type: application/json

Body:
{
    "name":"Contact email export",
    "fields":{
        "EmailAddress":"{{Contact.Field(C_EmailAddress)}}"
    }
}
```

**Response with content-type**

```
{
  "name": "Contact email export",
  "fields": {
    "EmailAddress": "{{Contact.Field(C_EmailAddress)}}"
  },
  "dataRetentionDuration": "PT12H",
  "uri": "/contacts/exports/2",
  "createdBy": "*****",
  "createdAt": "2016-03-09T14:33:03.0520813Z",
  "updatedBy": "*****",
  "updatedAt": "2016-03-09T14:33:03.0520813Z"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your client might be including extra escape characters. Your definition is correct. Use a JSON formatter to validate the request body and copy+paste it to a program like fiddler and try it from there. I copy pasted the definition you posted and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for getting back to me. 
Actually, the cause for the error is that the `Accept` header was missing.
In order to successfully execute the request, it should include one of the following:

`Accept: application/json`

or

`Accept: text/csv`